# $\mathrm{lcm}(b,c)$ from $\mathrm{lcm}(a,b)$ and $\mathrm{lcm}(a,c)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given that lcm$(a,b)=60$ and lcm$(a,c)=270$, find lcm$(b,c)$

I believe you're supposed to use the rule lcm$(a,b)=p_1^{\text{max}(r_1,s_1)}\cdots p_m^{\text{max}(r_m,s_m)}$

Here's my work so far:

lcm$(a,b)=60=2^2\cdot3\cdot5=2^{\text{max}(a_1,b_1)}\cdot3^{\text{max}(a_2,b_2)}\cdot5^{\text{max}(a_3,b_3)}$

and

lcm$(a,c)=270=2\cdot3^3\cdot5=2^{\text{max}(a_1,c_1)}\cdot3^{\text{max}(a_2,c_2)}\cdot5^{\text{max}(a_3,c_3)}$

Thus, max$(a_1,b_1)=3$ and max$(a_1,c_1)=1$. Clearly then, $a_1\ne3$, therefore $b_1=3$

Also, max$(a_2,b_2)=1$ and max$(a_2,c_2)=3$. Clearly then, $a_2\ne3$, therefore $c_2=3$

I'm a little stuck at this point. Am I even on the right track here?

Comment: You are on the right track! There need not be a unique value of lcm under the given conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\text{lcm}(a,b)=60=2^2\cdot3\cdot5$, $\;\;\;\max(a_1,b_1)=2, \max(a_2,b_2)=1, \max(a_3,b_3)=1$.

Since $\text{lcm}(a,c)=270=2\cdot3^3\cdot5$, $\;\;\max(a_1,c_1)=1, \max(a_2,c_2)=3, \max(a_3,c_3)=1$.

Therefore $b_1=2, c_2=3$ and $\;\;c_1\le1, \;b_2\le1, \text{ and } b_3,c_3\le1$;

so $\max(b_1,c_1)=2, \;\max(b_2,c_2)=3, \text{ and }\max(b_3,c_3)$ is either 0 or 1.

Thus $\text{lcm}(b,c)=2^2\cdot3^3=108$ $\;$or $\;\text{lcm}(b,c)=2^2\cdot3^3\cdot 5=540.$

Answer (score 0):

If $5$ doesn't divide $a$ it has to divide both $b$ and $c$ (since it divides both $\text{lcm}$s) and therefore it has to divide $\text{lcm}(b,c)$.

If $5$ does divide a$, it doesn't have to.